# Error SQL BLOB Syntax

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing, xampp, mariadb

Estoy Usando XAMPP MySQL y he creado una tabla a la que le he nombrado usuarios y dentro de esta e creado lo siguiente:

1. usuarioid: de tipo INT PRYMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
2. nombre: de tipo VARCHAR(20)
3. foto: de tipo BLOB

Cuando intento guardar la foto en java me presenta un error del SQL con relación a la sintaxis:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"usuarios"
(usuarioid, nombre, foto) VALUES (1, 'test', _binary'‰PNG

\0\0' at line 1
```

Aquí tengo el siguiente error que me sale en la base de datos cuando intento aplicar en BLOB el atributos BINARY:

```
Errores de consulta: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'BINARY NOT NULL' at line 1
```

Este es el método que he creado en Java para guardar la imagen:

```
try{
        String sql="INSERT INTO \"usuarios\"(usuarioid, nombre, foto) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement ps=con.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(txtcodigo.getText()));
        ps.setString(2,txtnombre.getText());
        ps.setBinaryStream(3,fis,longitudBytes);
        ps.execute();
        ps.close();

        lblfoto.setIcon(null);
        txtcodigo.setText("");
        txtnombre.setText("");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"Guardado correctamente");
    }catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException | HeadlessException x){
        System.out.println(""+x);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "exception 2 "+x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimina las comillas de la tabla usuarios. En SQL las tablas no se escriben entre comillas.